# Django, submiting a form via AJAX

Tags: ajax, django, django-bootstrap3

I have seen answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837312/django-taking-input-and-showing-output-in-the-same-page?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594976/submitting-a-django-form-in-a-bootstrap-modal)) for similar questions, but none of them work in my case. I have a simple form in a template, I am using bootstrap for rendering.

Once I submit the form, the response is rendered directly in the browser. When I return to the previous page (with the browser's button) then the **success** part of the AJAX call is executed.

**forms.py**

```
class QueryForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(label='Discover something', max_length=256)
```

**views.py**

```
def query_view(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Just for testing, send True
        response_data = {
            'result': True
        }

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
    else:
        try:
            # Create a form and send it to the template
            query_form = QueryForm()

            return render(request, 'query_template.html', {'query_form': query_form})
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return render(request, 'error.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^query', views.query_view, name='query_view'),
    url(r'^', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

**query_template.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block content %}

    {# Display a form #}
    <form method="post" class="form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% bootstrap_form query_form %}
        {% buttons %}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="query-button">
                {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Submit
            </button>
        {% endbuttons %}
    </form>
    <ul id="result"></ul>

    <script src="{% static 'scripts/main.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**main.js**

```
$('#query-button').click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/query/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
        cache: false,

        // handle a successful response
        success: function (json) {
            console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
            $("#result").html("<li>" + json.result + "</li>");
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});

// It also includes functions to manage the CRFS token
```

I have been playing with the code. If instead a form I use `<input>` and `<button id='query-button'>` it renders the response without reloading the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default submit action of the HTML form, via `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: However, I wrote the code based on [this post](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/). It did not work, then I started to debug and commented the line. I guess I was doing something else wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can using `FormData` instead of custom send data, open below links:

[How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData